# ExtJS: ajax based search form

Tags: extjs

I have an `Ext.form.Panel` that calls a PHP page by passing search parameters. The PHP page executes a query based on those params and returns a JSON structure. In the `form-success` handler I would like to get the JSON, build a store and fill a grid.
How can I do it using ajax? If I use `Ext.form.panel submit()` it always invoke `onFailure` because it does not find `[{success:val,message:msg}]`. Which is the correct way to build a form that gets back a JSON string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just have your search panel call a `load()` action on grid's JsonStore? A lot easier than manually flling the store from JSON string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; so, shouldn't i use forms but i have to get fields values and pass them in load() event?

Comment: Yes, you can use forms, but instead of colling `Ext.FormPanel.getForm().submit()` use `Ext.FormPanel.getForm().getValues()` to get an object with field names and values. You can use this object as `params` property in `Ext.data.Store.load()`, which will do all AJAX handling for you.